# Outsourcing functionality from Django view to C/C++

Tags: django

I'm developing a Django project that basically boils down to:

1. A user submits a form.
2. The Django view parses the form and compiles a representation of that form which is readable by some other 'function'. By 'function', I mean some kind of executable/callable where the Django view may be agnostic about what language that 'function' was written in, or even what hardware it runs on.
3. The Django view passes the compiled form into the 'function'.
4. The 'function' performs its business on the input, then outputs some data in a format readable by the Django view.
5. The Django view reads the output of the 'function' and renders the data to a format that is consumable by the user.

In my specific case, the 'function' is a large numerical computation not suitable for plain-vanilla Python. Furthermore, this 'function' has already been developed in C++11 and Python can talk to the compiled binary via os.system and file IO.

**My question then is:** *why should I not just use os.system or [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html) from the Django view* rather than

a) [redevelop the 'function' using one of ctypes | swig | Boost.Python | pyrex | cython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145270/calling-c-c-from-python);

b) [learn how to write Python extensions and re-write the 'function' accordingly](https://docs.python.org/3.4/extending/extending.html)?

I have also considered turning the 'function' into a daemon, but I am not experienced enough with daemons to be able to gauge what the consequences of such a design would be.

**Are there undesirable/undefined behaviours that would arise from using os.system/subprocess as described above for a Django project that was operating under load?**

Is there something else I am missing that is super obvious to everyone else?

There is also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091294/run-a-c-program-from-django-framework). But with the scarcity of details in both the OP's use case and in the answers, I am cautious not to fall for my own fallacious confirmation bias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wring with calling a library routine written in one language from an application written in another. It happens all the time. A good example is SQL code embedded in most other languages.

The issues you face with doing this is simply skillset, to maintain this external function you'll need to know C++ as well as python.

As you say, you have plenty of options for interfacing to this. I would recommend a ctypes mechanism as it will be the lowest overhead, that's almost the only consideration unless you cannot rebuild the function into a shared library. Making system calls to an external process works, its just a lot slower to get data to and from a process than it is to pass it to a shared library loaded in-process. You could convert the function into a web service and call it using SOAP or REST calls for example.

A daemon is just a process running that is running constantly. Its faster than simply running the function on-demand as the OS doesn't have to take all the time to start the process every time you want to call a function. To convert it into a daemon you might have to alter the code to run when several applications call the function simultaneously but otherwise its not any different.

So: if the speed of calling the function in a process is not important (eg its an intermittent, or long-running function) then go right ahead and call it using system calls. But, if you need speed, and this function returns quickly, or is called many time, then I think you should learn how C/C++ programs are written and built. Then you will have the skills to turn this into a library and call it using ctypes.